# Awaiting Angular router navigation in Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

Suppose I have a code fragment to test that:

- [`Navigate`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate)s (just to strip a query string parameter)
- `Then`, performs an HTTP call

I want to use the HTTP testing controller to match the corresponding request.

The following code obviously does not work

```
service.doStuff();
httpController.expectOne(...);
```

I tried to subscribe to Angular router's events, but yet no luck

```
router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) { // last event emitted
        httpController.expectOne(...); // still too early
    }
});
```

Basically my tests are failing because I am doing my expectation **too early** than the real http call (which I can debug, which **is** done after `router.navigate` returns the promise).

Code from `doStuff`

```
  from(this.router.navigate([], {
    relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
    queryParams: {
      token: null
    },
    queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
  }))
    .pipe(switchMap(() => this.doRemotely()))
    .subscribe(result => {
      .....
    });
}
```

The `doRemotely` is activated correctly after the navigation promise returned, but I can't intercept it.

I was thinking of mocking the router... Any ideas on the proper way to run the expectation *after* the HTTP call has been issued?

[Edit] using `callFake` on a Jasmine spy would not likely solve my problem, as I can't do the expecatation after the fake promise returned. Yet, a mocked router helps isolate the test.

Comment: are you using real Router for your tests?

Comment: No, `RouterTestingModule` with a `provide`d `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: and how do you handle asynchroniouty in your test?

Comment: i mean do you use fakeAsync or maybe async await

Comment: I did not mention the `done` function in the question, but my idea is to 1) subscribe to the correct event and 2) issue the done function after the expectations are satisfied. The problem is that the test fails because the expectations are not satisfied. I found, by debugging, that the NavigationEnd event is issued before the promise returns, so before the unit under test does `switchMap`. The unit under test currently does not publish events to tell around "hey, I've done an http call" to which I could subscribe

Comment: I see. I would use fakeAsync in tests and flush all async events before assertions

Comment: Also, something that can help you is to do `await router.initialNavigation()`. This will wait until the initial navigation is completed before carrying on.

Answer (score 0):

Using real routes in a test is a tricky thing. However you could try to do something similar to that https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/guides/route, to init routes in the test properly:

```js
describe('TestRoute:Route', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    // Providing a route testing module is important
    imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
      // routes
    ])],
  }).compileComponents());

  // fakeAsync is important
  it('renders', fakeAsync(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RouterOutlet);
    const router: Router = TestBed.inject(Router);
    const location: Location = TestBed.inject(Location);

    // First we need to initialize navigation.
    location.go('/1');
    if (fixture.ngZone) {
      fixture.ngZone.run(() => router.initialNavigation());
      tick(); // is needed for rendering of the current route.
    }

    // We should land to the desired route.
    expect(location.path()).toEqual('/1');
  }));
});
```

Comment: TestBed.get() is deprecated now. :(

Comment: Hi. You can use TestBed.inject() instead